# Resize view created from xib based on label length

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a UIView created from an xib. In the view I have a text label which has its value set dynamically. This view is being used in as a custom map callout. I want the text to affect the width of the callout but the text is simply truncated. If I change the width of the view in the xib file then the callout is wider as expected. Is there any way to have the callout/xib view expand to fit the text instead of causing the text to be truncated?

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing directions and not implementing this, but for anyone who is having trouble resizing nib views try disabling autoresizing. There have been quite a few times where my nib view is not behaving as expected and this is usually the cause. You can disable Autoresizing in the view editor like so:

[image: storyboard autoresizing view]

Answer (score -2):

First, make sure that the leading and trailing edges have constraints to the view that you want to be resized.

Then increase horizontal `Content Compression Resistance Priority` of the label, probably, up to 1000.

[image: Content Compression Resistance Priority]